# How to see the execution steps of a java program

Tags: java, eclipse

I know that Eclipse have a function that allow us to see the steps of execution of a program.

Can anyone tell me how can I find it? I really need it to study and understand some pices of code.

Comment: You should compile with `-g` switch.

Comment: What do you want to do? Maybe the word you are searching for is "debugging"?

Comment: It's called debugger. You can run your app inside it using the bug-like icon next to the "run" one (that looks like the play button)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Look for the little green bug at the top. 
If you run it by pressing this icon, your application will run in a new perspective and stop at your breakpoints.

[image]

Enter breakpoints by clicking the area where you see the blue dot in this picture.

[image]

Navigate inside of the debugger with:

[image]

Green arrow is for running till next breakpoint.
Red square is for terminating the process.
The 90degree arrow goes into methods you invoke showing each step IN the method. The last arrow executes them without showing the steps.

If you're done with debugging you can switch perspective here.(upper right corner)
[image]

Answer (score 5):

Executing your java program step by step you need to follow a few steps:

- Set a breakpoint by double-clicking left of the very first line of your program, which seems to be something like `public static void main(String[] args)`.
  The breakpoint looks like this -> [image]
- Open your program in the [image] view. (in the standard layout this could be found in the top right corner of your eclipse ide)
- Start running your program in debug mode [image] (in the standard layout this could be found in the toolbar at the top of your eclipse ide)
- Now you can easily navigate through your program by using the F5-F7 buttons or clicking these icons in the top toolbar [image]

For deeper insight look at the tutorial [Here](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseDebugging/article.html)