# How to find the execution steps of an Eclipse plugin project

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I am using Eclipse JUNO IDE in which I have imported an eclipse plugin project.

When I execute the project, a new copy of the eclipse window is opened and the plugin is displayed in the File Menu as "New Sample Project" in between the "New" option and "Open File" option. The plugin works normally.

From this project I wanted to know which file executes first and how the execution proceeds.

While [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22131224/how-to-see-the-execution-steps-of-a-java-program/22131370#22131370) is the way to find the order of execution of a simple java program, is there a way to find the code execution order of a plugin project, which has many packages and each package has many java files?

I am new to eclipse plug-in development. Please help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eclipse plugin project is different than normal Java project and also its execution.

Before jumping into execution steps, I think you better go through plugin project [Manifest file details](http://help.eclipse.org/mars/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.pde.doc.user%2Fguide%2Ftools%2Feditors%2Fmanifest_editor%2Feditor.htm). It will give you overview of plugins that are contributed into your new eclipse instant and their implementation class in project.

Go through different tab in the manifest file. I will brief some of important things for you:

**Overview:** General info of you plugin. In general information section you will find Activator, which points your activator of plugin which will load your plugin.*(You can say it as starting point as it controls plugin life cycle but not clearly starting point)*

**Dependencies:** Plugins required and on which your projects are depended.

**Extension:** Here you will add Extension Points required for your plugin like view, editor, action,command. Here you can see overview of things which will be contributed through your plugin project.

Hope this helps.